# .append not working on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Simple button that should be creating new `<p>` elements when its clicked but it isn't working and I'm not sure why as I've compared it to other code of mine.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x8cfh4dd/2/)

```
var battle = function() {
    while(monsterHP > 0){
        var playerDam = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((playerAtk - monsterAtk) + 2);
        $('#battle').append("<p>You have hit the monster for " + playerDam + " damage. The monster has " + (monsterHP - playerDam) + "HP left</p>");
        monsterHP -= playerDam;
        if(monsterHP <= 0) {
            $('#battle').append("<p>You have defeated the monster</p>");
        }
    }
}

$('#battleButton').click(function() {
    battle();
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the browser console? There’s a syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have many syntax errors in your code. If you correct them (as below), then it works fine. When you write a JQuery append, you need to put a ')' after your argument. Likewise, functions need to have a '}' after them.

```
var playerAtk = 5;
var playerDef = 5;
var playerHP = 10;
var monsterAtk = 4;
var monsterDef = 4;
var monsterHP = 8;

var battle = function() {
    while(monsterHP > 0){
        var playerDam = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((playerAtk - monsterAtk) + 2));
        $('#battle').append("<p>You have hit the monster for " + playerDam + " damage. The monster has " + (monsterHP - playerDam) + "HP left</p>");
        monsterHP -= playerDam;
        if(monsterHP <= 0) {
            $('#battle').append("<p>You have defeated the monster</p>");
        }
    }
}

$('#battleButton').click(function() {
    battle();
});
```

Comment: thanks figured this out right before you answered, guess I posted too hastily.

Comment: @Shniper if this answered your question, pls mark it as answered. TY